# Instagram API Rate Limiting - Signed POST calls - still being treated like unsigned calls

Tags: api, rest, instagram

Instagram changed the way it rate limits like, comment and relationship endpoints in its API recently...you can sign API POST requests with an HMAC hash of your client secret and app IP address. I am doing this successfully. I know this because I get a 403 error message if I don't include the a properly hashed X-Insta-Forwarded-For header; get a 200 success message if it is included).

Still, I'm being rate-limited to 30 "like" calls per hour (the limit for unsigned requests); 100 is the limit for signed requests. Anyone know why this might be?

Updated docs are here: http://instagram.com/developer/restrict-api-requests/

and

here: http://instagram.com/developer/limits/

Comment: I guess you have to ask them about their policies

Answer (score 1):

Apparently my Instagram client credentials had been flagged by Instagram, and they were limiting me based on past behavior of my app. I registered a new client with Instagram here: http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/, re-authenticated with the new app, plugged the new secret into my code to sign my requests, and I was able to like 100 IG posts within an hour. Good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I managed to solve it by simply revoking app token from user panel. No need to create new app.